# Looking for techniques for enumerating classes of solutions to Hamming weight constrained sums

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

I am looking for a quick way of generating general classes of solutions to a set of problems. There will be 5 or less positive integer variables ($a,...,e$) ordered by size ($a \geq b \geq...\geq e$).
Depending on the problem I want to enumerate $a,...,e$ might have a Hamming weight *(number of 1 bits in the number's binary representation)* of between 1 and 4 (so be $2^w$ or $2^w+2^x$ or $2^w+2^x+2^y$ etc).
I need the sum of the variable to be within a range $2^{l-2}\leq a+b+c+d+e< 2^{l-1}$.

So I might try something like this (but omitting the hamming weight):

```
FindInstance[2^(l - 4) >= a >= b >= c >= d >= e > 0 && 
  2^(l - 2) <= a + b + c + d + e < 2^(l - 1), {a, b, c, d, e, l}, Integers]
```

For a Hamming weight of only 1 for the 5 variables there is only 2 essential solutions $(a,...,e)$: $(2^{l-4},2^{l-4},2^{l-4},2^{l-4},2^q),q\leq l-4$ and $(2^{l-4},2^{l-4},2^{l-4},2^{l-5},2^{l-5})$

That's the only 5 variable problem I have. For example with 4 variables ($a,..,d$) I have two problems where one can have variables with a Hamming weight of 2 or less and the other must have Hamming weight 1 or less. The bounds of the variables and sum are different but similar to the example.

An example in 4 variables using FindInstance would be:

`FindInstance[2^(l - 3) >= a >= b >= c >= d > 0 && 2^(l - 2) <= a + b + c + d < 2^(l - 1) && a == 2^q && b == 2^r && c == 2^s && d == 2^t && l == 8, {a, b, c, d, l, q, r, s, t}, Integers, 100]`

The only way I could find to get mathematica to produce results is to fix l.

Comment: Maybe you could add a quick explanation of how hamming weight  works. This might make the question easier to approach.

Comment: Hamming weight is just the number of 1 bits in the binary representation of the number. So for example having a hamming weight of 4 would mean a number is of the form $2^w+2^x+2^y+2^z,w>x>y>z$. Mathematica seems to have a hard time with expressions like the one in my main post that contain exponentials.

Comment: So would the Hamming weight of a number, say, 2147, correspond to  `DigitCount[2147, 2, 1]`? Also, if possible, can you add a fully worked out instance with solutions for a very small case (where you could maybe find the solutions with brute force), just to give something to work with?

Comment: That's correct. DigitCount the way you use it gives the hamming weight. You cant use this in FindInstance though.

Answer (score 3):

I would change variables from integers to the binary digits of each of the integers. For your example, there are 4 integers, and each integer $i$ is constrained to be $0 < i \le 32$, so there are at most 6 binary digits in each integer. Hence, the following array can be used:

```
v = Array[i, {4, 6}]
```

> {{i[1, 1], i[1, 2], i[1, 3], i[1, 4], i[1, 5], i[1, 6]}, {i[2, 1], i[2, 2], 
>     i[2, 3], i[2, 4], i[2, 5], i[2, 6]}, {i[3, 1], i[3, 2], i[3, 3], i[3, 4], 
>     i[3, 5], i[3, 6]}, {i[4, 1], i[4, 2], i[4, 3], i[4, 4], i[4, 5], i[4, 6]}}

The value of each integer is given by:

```
values = v . 2^Range[0,5]
```

> {i[1, 1] + 2 i[1, 2] + 4 i[1, 3] + 8 i[1, 4] + 16 i[1, 5] + 32 i[1, 6], 
>    i[2, 1] + 2 i[2, 2] + 4 i[2, 3] + 8 i[2, 4] + 16 i[2, 5] + 32 i[2, 6], 
>    i[3, 1] + 2 i[3, 2] + 4 i[3, 3] + 8 i[3, 4] + 16 i[3, 5] + 32 i[3, 6], 
>    i[4, 1] + 2 i[4, 2] + 4 i[4, 3] + 8 i[4, 4] + 16 i[4, 5] + 32 i[4, 6]}

The Hamming weight of each integer is given by:

```
weight = v . {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
```

> {i[1, 1] + i[1, 2] + i[1, 3] + i[1, 4] + i[1, 5] + i[1, 6], 
>    i[2, 1] + i[2, 2] + i[2, 3] + i[2, 4] + i[2, 5] + i[2, 6], 
>    i[3, 1] + i[3, 2] + i[3, 3] + i[3, 4] + i[3, 5] + i[3, 6], 
>    i[4, 1] + i[4, 2] + i[4, 3] + i[4, 4] + i[4, 5] + i[4, 6]}

Finally, each binary digit can only be 0 or 1. I will use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) instead of [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance) in order to get all solutions:

```
res = Solve[
    And[
        And @@ Thread[0 < values <= 32],
        2^6 <= Total[values] < 2^7,
        And @@ Thread[weight == 1],
        And @@ Thread[0 <= Flatten[v] <= 1],
        LessEqual @@ values
    ],
    Flatten[v],
    Integers
];

values /. res
```

> {{16, 32, 32, 32}, {16, 16, 32, 32}, {16, 16, 16, 32}, {16, 16, 16, 
>     16}, {8, 32, 32, 32}, {8, 16, 32, 32}, {8, 16, 16, 32}, {8, 8, 32, 
>     32}, {8, 8, 16, 32}, {4, 32, 32, 32}, {4, 16, 32, 32}, {4, 16, 16, 
>     32}, {4, 8, 32, 32}, {4, 4, 32, 32}, {2, 32, 32, 32}, {2, 16, 32, 
>     32}, {2, 16, 16, 32}, {2, 8, 32, 32}, {2, 4, 32, 32}, {2, 2, 32, 
>     32}, {1, 32, 32, 32}, {1, 16, 32, 32}, {1, 16, 16, 32}, {1, 8, 32, 
>     32}, {1, 4, 32, 32}, {1, 2, 32, 32}, {1, 1, 32, 32}}